# XML Transform for ASP.Net TreeView Control

Tags: asp.net, xml, treeview

Not being an XML expert I'm struggling with this:

I need to populate an ASP.Net Treeview control from an XML dataSource. I can usually do this no problem except on this occasion the data I've been provided with is in this format:

```
<Staff>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>Boss 1</Name>
<JobTitle>Top Boss</JobTitle>
<Staff>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Boss 2</Name>
    <JobTitle>2nd Top Boss</JobTitle>
    <Staff>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Name>Boss 3</Name>
        <JobTitle>3rd Top Boss</JobTitle>
        <Staff>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <Name>Worker 1</Name>
            <JobTitle>Worker</JobTitle>
        </Staff>
    </Staff>
</Staff>
</Staff>
```

and I need it to be like this for the treeview control:

```
<Staff ID="1" Name="Boss 1" JobTitle="Top Boss">
  <Staff ID="2" Name="Boss 2" JobTitle="2nd Top Boss" >
    <Staff ID="3" Name="Boss 3" JobTitle="3rd Top Boss" >
        <Staff ID="4" Name="Worker 1" JobTitle="Worker" ></Staff>
    </Staff>
  </Staff>
</Staff>
```

I know this should be a doddle to do with an xsl file, but I'm failing miserably. My last attempt was:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Staff">
    <Staff>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Staff>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Staff">
    <Staff>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </Staff>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predictably I figured it out 30mins after posting. The following converts the xml above to the required format and appears to transform any xml elements to attibutes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*|*[not(* or @*)]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[* or @*]|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```